# 60’s/70’s movie where Earth’s society becomes so germophobic that they have no immune system

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie that was probably made back in the 60’s or 70’s.  It involved Earth’s society, so germophobic that it destroyed their own immune systems and everyone was getting sick and dying off. But they were blaming a scientist that lived in a biodome filled with plant life.  At the end of the book the citizens destroy the dome and release the natural bacteria needed in life to build the immune system.

Comment: Is this a book or movie? You say both so just want to clarify. Also if you remember anything else please [edit] your question to include that information.